# Error stopping Telegram bot callback using Telebot

Tags: python, callback, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm developing a Telegram bot using the Telebot library in Python. The bot has a main menu with two commands: /cep and /person. When using the /cep command, the user must enter a zip code to obtain related information. After processing the zip code, the bot displays the details and offers a "Main Menu" button to return to the home screen, which would be equivalent to the /start command.

The problem occurs when I try to use the "Main Menu" button after querying the ZIP code. The callback associated with the button is not interrupting the flow and returning to the welcome message. It gets stuck inside the process_cep_input function, resulting in unwanted behavior.

```
import telebot
import requests, json
from telebot import types

TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN = 'SECRET_TOKEN'
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token=TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN, parse_mode='HTML')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def handler_start(message):
  welcome_message = (
    f'Olá {message.from_user.first_name}. Tudo bem?\n\n'
    'Veja o que posso fazer por você:\n'
    '1. /cep - Consultar informações de um CEP\n'
    '2. /pessoa - Gerar uma pessoa fictícia com IA\n\n'
    'Escreva abaixo o comando que deseja utilizar ou clique diretamente acima.'
  )
  bot.send_message(chat_id=message.from_user.id, text=welcome_message)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['cep'])
def handler_cep(message):
    bot.send_message(chat_id=message.from_user.id, text='Legal, vamos consultar um CEP.\n\nPor favor, digite o CEP que você deseja consultar informando <u><b>apenas números</b></u>, conforme o exemplo: <i>XXXXXXXX</i>')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['cep'])
def process_cep_input(message):
  try:
    cep_solicitado = int(message.text)
    url_api = f'https://viacep.com.br/ws/{cep_solicitado}/json/'
    request = requests.get(url_api)

    if request.status_code == 200:
      dicionario = json.loads(request.content.decode('utf-8'))
      mensagem = 'Essas são as informações do CEP solicitado! \n\nCEP: {}\nLogradouro: {}\nBairro: {}\nCidade: {}\nEstado: {}\nDDD da Região: {}\n\nInforme outro CEP para uma nova busca ou volte ao menu anterior.'
      markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
      markup.add(
        types.InlineKeyboardButton('Menu Principal', callback_data='/chatbot main menu')
      )
      bot.send_chat_action(chat_id=message.from_user.id, action='typing')
      bot.send_message(chat_id=message.from_user.id, text=mensagem.format(dicionario['cep'], dicionario['logradouro'], dicionario['bairro'], dicionario['localidade'], dicionario['uf'], dicionario['ddd']), reply_to_message_id=message.message_id, reply_markup=markup)
      bot.register_next_step_handler(message, process_cep_input)

    else:
      bot.send_message(chat_id=message.from_user.id, text=' Dados incorretos. Por favor, informe um CEP válido.', reply_to_message_id=message.message_id)
      bot.register_next_step_handler(message, process_cep_input)

  except:
    bot.send_message(chat_id=message.from_user.id, text=' Dados incorretos. Por favor, informe um CEP válido.', reply_to_message_id=message.message_id)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, process_cep_input)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_handler(call):
  if call.data == '/chatbot main menu':
     handler_start(call)
```

In an attempt to interrupt the `/chatbot main_menu` callback and return to the main menu. I used the `callback_handler` function to handle the callbacks and tried calling the `handler_start` function inside it to send a welcome message and restart the user interaction. However, this is not working as expected. What I expected to receive was a successful callback interruption and a transition to the welcome message in the bot's main menu, related to the `/start` command. I'm asking for guidance on how to fix this issue and effectively stop the callback in Telebot.

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: why do you have two `commands=['cep']`? One for `handler_cep()` and second for `process_cep_input()`

Comment: when you create Button then you use `bot.register_next_step_handler(..., process_cep_input)` - maybe you should use `handler_start` instead `process_cep_input`?

Comment: I try you code but you have some mistakes and it can't work - first you have two `commands=['cep']` and it aways runs `handler_cep() ` but not `process_cep_input()`. Second: don't conver zip code to integer - example on page shows `viacep.com.br/ws/01001000/json/ ` and converting `01001000` to `int()` gives error - you should keep it as string. I wonder how you could even run it.

Comment: maybe you should run `import logging` and `telebot.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)` to see all messages from bot.

Comment: when I use `print( request.status_code )` then it gives `400`, not `200` - so this code couldn't work.

Comment: another mistake: when you try to do `cep_solicitado = int(message.text)` then `message.text` has `/cep 01001000` and you should remove `/cep` from string. You have so many mistakes in code - I don't understand how you could see `Button`.

Comment: your code finally works for me - and Button shows `welcome message` like `/start` - so it is the only thing which works, but you described that this is the only thing which doesn't work for you. You have to run totally different code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you have problem with Button but I tested all code and there was many mistakes (so code couldn't run) and only Button was working correctly. So I don't understand your problem.

You have two `commands=['cep']` and it always runs first function `handler_cep()` instead of `process_cep_handler()` - and it can't even display `Button`.

In `process_cep_handler()` you convert full message to `int()` and this makes two problems

- full message is `/cep 0100100` and you have to remove `/cep`
- number `01001000` can't be converted to integer because it could lost first `zero` and keep as `1001000`. Besides [documentations](https://viacep.com.br/) show also examples like `95010A10` with char `A` - so you should keep it as string.

Frankly, `InlineKeyboardButton` doesn't need `register_next_step_handler`.

---

I put my full working code which I used to test problem.

I added `telebot.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)` to see information from `bot`.
I also use `print()` to check which part of code is executedm and what is variables.

```
import telebot
import requests, json
from telebot import types
import os

import logging
telebot.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG) # Outputs debug messages to console.

#TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN = 'SECRET_TOKEN'
TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN = os.getenv('TELEGRAM_TOKEN')

bot = telebot.TeleBot(token=TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN, parse_mode='HTML')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def handler_start(message):
    welcome_message = (
        f'Olá {message.from_user.first_name}. Tudo bem?\n\n'
        'Veja o que posso fazer por você:\n'
        '1. /cep - Consultar informações de um CEP\n'
        '2. /pessoa - Gerar uma pessoa fictícia com IA\n\n'
        'Escreva abaixo o comando que deseja utilizar ou clique diretamente acima.'
    )
    bot.send_message(chat_id=message.from_user.id, text=welcome_message)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['cep'])
def process_cep_input(message):
    print('[DEBUG]: process_cep_input()')

    try:
        print('[DEBUG] message.text:', message.text)
        
        # `message.text` is `/cep 0100100` and it needs to remove `/cep` 
        items = message.text.split()
        
        if len(items) < 2 and items[0] == '/cep':
            bot.send_message(chat_id=message.from_user.id, text="it needs code - ie. 0100100")
            bot.register_next_step_handler(message, process_cep_input)
            return
            
        cep_solicitado = items[-1]  # get last element without converting to `int`

        url_api = f'https://viacep.com.br/ws/{cep_solicitado}/json/'
        print('[DEBUG] url_api:', url_api)

        #headers = {
        #    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:98.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/98.0',
        #}
        response = requests.get(url_api) #, headers=headers)
        print('[DEBUG] response.status_code:', response.status_code)
        print('[DEBUG] response.text:', response.text)

        if response.status_code == 200:
            print('[DEBUG]: STATUS OK')
            #dicionario = json.loads(request.content.decode('utf-8'))
            dicionario = response.json()
            
            mensagem = 'Essas são as informações do CEP solicitado! \n\nCEP: {}\nLogradouro: {}\nBairro: {}\nCidade: {}\nEstado: {}\nDDD da Região: {}\n\nInforme outro CEP para uma nova busca ou volte ao menu anterior.'
            markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
            markup.add(
                types.InlineKeyboardButton('Menu Principal', callback_data='/chatbot main menu')
            )
            bot.send_chat_action(chat_id=message.from_user.id, action='typing')
            bot.send_message(chat_id=message.from_user.id, text=mensagem.format(dicionario['cep'], dicionario['logradouro'], dicionario['bairro'], dicionario['localidade'], dicionario['uf'], dicionario['ddd']), reply_to_message_id=message.message_id, reply_markup=markup)
            #bot.register_next_step_handler(message, process_cep_input)       # it seems it doesn't use it 
            #bot.register_next_step_handler(message, callback_handler)        # it seems it doesn't use it 
            #bot.register_next_step_handler(message, other_callback_handler)  # it seems it doesn't use it 
            
        else:
            bot.send_message(chat_id=message.from_user.id, text=' Dados incorretos. Por favor, informe um CEP válido.', reply_to_message_id=message.message_id)
            bot.register_next_step_handler(message, process_cep_input)

    except Exception as ex:
        print('[DEBUG] Exception:', ex)
        bot.send_message(chat_id=message.from_user.id, text=' Dados incorretos. Por favor, informe um CEP válido.', reply_to_message_id=message.message_id)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, process_cep_input)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data == '/chatbot main menu')
def other_callback_handler(call):
    #print('[DEBUG] other_callback_handler:', dir(call))
    print('[DEBUG] other_callback_handler:', call.data)
    #print('[DEBUG] other_callback_handler:', call.message)
    
    handler_start(call)     
         
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_handler(call):
    #print('[DEBUG] callback_handler:', dir(call))
    print('[DEBUG] callback_handler:', call.data)
    #print('[DEBUG] callback_handler:', call.message)
    
    if call.data == '/chatbot main menu':
        handler_start(call)     

if __name__ == '__main__':        
    bot.infinity_polling()
```

Comment: Thank you, your contribution helped me solve the code that wasn't working as expected. Now it's working and I've managed to adapt other functions to work correctly.